# Can't fetch Smart Albums in AppleScript after upgrading to Catalina

Tags: applescript, apple-photos

I've been using an AppleScript to export photos in a Smart Album in Apple Photos for a while now. After upgrading to Catalina, it seems that my query for all albums no longer returns Smart Albums.

Specifically, I have a line that loads all albums like this:

```
tell Application Photos
    set theseAlbums to every album
    ...
end tell
```

Previously, `theseAlbums` would contain regular and smart albums. After upgrading to Catalina, they only contain the regular (non-smart) ones.

Is there anything I can do to query for smart albums? I looked at the Photos Dictionary and didn't see anything. I also tried changing `every album` to `every container` with no luck.

Here's the code in context - a helper function that finds an album by name:

```
on getAlbumNamed(thisName)
    tell application "Photos"
        set theseAlbums to every album
        repeat with i from 1 to the count of theseAlbums
            set thisAlbum to item i of theseAlbums
            if the name of thisAlbum is thisName then
                return thisAlbum
            end if
        end repeat
    end tell
end getAlbumNamed
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Have you found any solution yet ?

Comment: Sadly, no. I've had to work around it by creating regular albums and manually moving things from the smart albums into the regular ones before running my apple script.